# Postgres put Data into groups by similar date

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a tabler i will call `data_rows` like this:

```
create table if not exists data_rows
(
    id                integer  not null,
    constraint data_rows_to_group
        primary key (id),
    date              date     not null,
    group_id          int, 
    --more fields that are not relevant
);
```

When i order the rows by date i want the rows to have a new group_id if the date difference to the preceding row is >7 days (can be another time_span but lets keep it at 7 days)
So all rows that have the same group_id when ordered by date have a date differences <= 7 days.
For example:

```
id      date        group id
1      12.01.2019   0
2      15.01.2019   0
3      21.01.2019   0
4      05.02.2019   1
5      08.02.2019   1
6      20.02.2019   2
7      30.02.2019   3
8      30.02.2019   3
```

(Especially 1 and 3 are in the same group although they have a difference >7 but in the group two following rows have no difference >7)

I know how to do this in python or c# or similar languages in a procedural way. 
But it would be very useful if i could do this on the postgresql server because it is a lot of data and it keeps it to a single point of failure too and it would be a big learning experience too.

Here is how i would do it in c# so you get the idea of what i want:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class DataRows
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}

class GroupMarking
{
    public DataRows[] RowsWithGroupIds(IEnumerable<DataRows> relevantDataRows, TimeSpan betweenSpan)
    {
        var currentGroupId = 0;
        var rows = relevantDataRows.OrderBy(p => p.Date).ToArray();
        rows[0].GroupId = currentGroupId;
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.Length; i++)
        {
            if (rows[i].Date -
                rows[i - 1].Date >= betweenSpan)
            {
                currentGroupId++;
            }
            rows[i].GroupId = currentGroupId;
        }
        return rows;
    }
}
```

Is this possible in postgresql? I know there are Loops in Postgres. I prefer a solution without loops but if its not possible without they are ok.
How do i create the ids int the group_id column without falling back on a procedural language?

Comment: You should try to do this at several iterations, on each iteration you will add one of your business rules to the SQL query. For example, first try to define a formula which will calculate the group ID from any given date - by using the provided `date_span` argument. Then you will try to add the rule for groups of no less than 2 rows. Then the next rule ... until you come up with a final SQL query. If it is impossible to build such a query - then you can simply write an imperative SQL procedure directly translating C# to SQL.

Comment: @IVOGELOV i tried to clarify the question a bit more. I added those extra rules as context but they are not the problem. My roblem is the grouping by date differences

Comment: Well, you should start with a definition of this `date_span` - at least to prevent ambiguity like this: `If there are 3 rows in sequence and row 2 is within the date_span relative to both row 1 and row 3 - then which of these 2 groups should we put row 2 in ?` Implementation comes from the definition.

Comment: @IVOGELOV changed the question a lot to make more clear what i need

Comment: Unrelated, but: `30.02.2019` is an invalid date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem which can be solved by turning the information if the difference is bigger than 7 days into a flag, and then summing that flag:

```
select id, "date", sum(flag) over (order by "date") as group_id
from (
  select id, "date", 
         ("date" - lag("date", 1, "date") over (order by "date") > 7)::int as flag
  from data_rows
) t
order by "date"
```

The expression `"date" - lag("date", 1, "date") over (order by "date")` calculates the difference in dates between the "current" row and the previous one. This is then checked if it's greater than 7 days and the boolean is converted to an integer (0, 1) so that the outer running sum can be used on it.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0dac0d723d44352df317ffdea4ab941f)

<sup>(I replaced the invalid date 2019-02-30 with 2019-02-28)</sup>